Build a query circuit that set the first bit to 0
This is a question from Chapter 2, 8(c) in Quantum Computing: Lecture notes by Ronald de Wolf.
Suppose we can make queries of the type $|i, b\rangle→ |i, b\oplus x_i\rangle$ to input $x\in\{0, 1\}^N, N = 2^n$. How to implement a query to an input $x'$ that is obtained from $x$ by setting its first bit to 0 (e.g. if $x=111$ then $x'=011$). We may use one query to $x$. And I assume we can use any number of elementary gates including X, Y, Z, CNOT and Toffoli.
I think we might need several auxiliary qubits to store the value of $b$ and $x_0$ but I don't really know how to reset them to 0. Am I on the right track? thanks!
